# how to Import PHP method into HTML. I'm new; what are my opions

Tags: php, html, sql, import

I'm stuck trying to find a way to import a php method into a html index. The PHP function is to store user input into a sql database. I just need to html syntax for importing php scripts. 
Thank you

Comment: The syntax for importing php scripts into html is renaming the .html to .php....or calling the php files from html/javascript via ajax.

Comment: So I have to force my web server to load PHP index instead of HTML. That seems easier than using the ajax method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot import PHP files in a HTML file.

Comment: Would you suggest I force my web server to run a php index, or use html/jscript via ajax?

Comment: `Ajax` as you already know would be the best practice. Or render the website with your data you get from somewhere. Logic > Format Data > Render (= render a HTML output with your data). Just like any `CMS` is doing.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I'll use the Ajax method.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side scripting language.  HTML is entirely browser side.  You cannot execute server side code from your browser.  They are two totally different things.

You can, however, pass information from your PHP results to your HTML using JavaScript.

```
<?php
$thisVariable = "hello world";
?>

<script>
var thisVariable = '<? echo $thisVariable ?>'
</script>
```

That's really about the best you can do.

Comment: Thank you; although i'm a newbie, my instincts where, that html couldn't handle a php function.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that the FIRST thing to do is rename your file with a PHP extension.  Then, with no other changes, it can handle PHP code.